# Problem in function map(), Caused by error in `UseMethod()`

Tags: html, r, dictionary

I tried to map a folder of .html files into RDS, but sometimes the function fails as below

```
html_files <- list.files(file_directory, full.names = TRUE, recursive=TRUE)

rip_text <- function(court_file){

ripped_text <- read_html(court_file, options = "HUGE") |>
html_text2() |> # Pull out only the text
str_remove('^.*PubDate":"\\d{4}-\\d\\d-\\d\\d",\n') |> 
str_remove('\\}"; var jsonData.*$') 
return(ripped_text)}'

ripped_files <- map(html_files, rip_text)
```

Here is the error:
Error in `map()`:
i In index: 19531.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'xml_find_first' applied to an object of class "xml_document"
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Have you looked at `ripped_text[19530:19532]` to see what is different about the middle element? There's nothing we can know about it without a reproducible question.

Comment: This error is far more likely to be the result of bad data input rather than the `map` function itself. It sounds like one of the documents you are trying to read might not be a properly formatted HTML file. It's really hard to help without any sort of reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care too much about excluding the couple of errors in question and want the bulk of the data, you could use `purrr::safely()`, as follows.

```
html_files <- list.files(file_directory, full.names = TRUE, recursive=TRUE)

rip_text <- function(court_file){
  read_html(court_file, options = "HUGE") |>
    html_text2() |> # Pull out only the text
    str_remove('^.*PubDate":"\\d{4}-\\d\\d-\\d\\d",\n') |> 
    str_remove('\\}"; var jsonData.*$')
  }

rip_text_safe <- safely(rip_text)

ripped_files <- map(html_files, rip_text_safe)
```

I can't test this (as I understandably don't have the files) but this should work for you.